# Naive Gaussian Elimination vs Scaled Partial Pivoting

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Just a quick question.
Say I was to write a function in Matlab that performs Naive Gaussian Elimination for solving Ax=b and another function in Matlab that performs Scaled Partial Pivoting.  My question is would the code for the back substitution change part of solving for $x_1$,$x_2$,etc or would it would be exactly the same for both functions? My hunch is that the code would be exactly the same for the back substitution part by I'm not entirely sure.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Backward and forward substitutions are the same for both variants. With partial pivoting, you have $PA=LU$ with $P$ being a permutation matrix (stored in a form of a permutation vector for efficiency), so $x=A^{-1}b=U^{-1}L^{-1}Pb$.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel     So the code for backward and forward substitutions would remain exactly the same?

Comment: Indeed the only thing which changes is that you ship it a permuted right hand side vector and possibly permute the solution vector at the end in case you’d use also column permutations.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel so if I didn't use column permutations, then I don't have to permute anything at the end?

Comment: yes $~~~~~~~~~~~~$